# java.lang.AssertionError: Docker environment has more than 2GB free

Tags: java, docker, testing, out-of-memory

I have been creating tests for my program that uses docker. And everything was working well until suddently I face this problem at the start of any test

```
ℹ︎ Checking the system...
    ✔ Docker version is newer than 1.6.0
    ✘ Docker environment has more than 2GB free

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

java.lang.AssertionError: Docker environment has more than 2GB free

at org.rnorth.visibleassertions.VisibleAssertions.fail(VisibleAssertions.java:437)
at org.rnorth.visibleassertions.VisibleAssertions.assertTrue(VisibleAssertions.java:129)
at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.checkDiskSpace(DockerClientFactory.java:168)
at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.lambda$client$1(DockerClientFactory.java:127)
at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.runInsideDocker(DockerClientFactory.java:230)
at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:118)
at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.<init>(GenericContainer.java:116)
at my.project.historyservice.MongoDBTest.<clinit>(MongoDBTest.java:24)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:156)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1088)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1069)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkField.get(FrameworkField.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getAnnotatedFieldValues(TestClass.java:230)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.classRules(ParentRunner.java:255)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.withClassRules(ParentRunner.java:244)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.classBlock(ParentRunner.java:194)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:362)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

The class MongoDBTest starts with:

```
public class MongoDBTest
{
  @ClassRule
  public static GenericContainer mongodb = new GenericContainer("mongo:3.6")
          .withExposedPorts(27017)
          .waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort());
```

With line 24 being the one where I call "new GenericContainer"

I cant figure out what can be the problem. My computer has 16GB of RAM, out of which about 10GB should be free. I ran the test about 10 times successfully today before the problem arose, and I have tried restarting computer but it didnt help.

Comment: It is checking your _Disk_ space, not your RAM.

Comment: Thank you! I got the problem fixed by deleting some files from my disk.

Comment: In my case, even if I had removed files from the disk, only that worked was this command: docker stop $(docker ps -a -q);docker kill $(docker ps -q);docker rm $(docker ps -a -q);docker rmi $(docker images -q)

Answer (score 5):

`docker rmi $(docker images -q)` does the trick thanks to @pafede2

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes volume data is the culprit (at least it was for me).

Removing unused volumes and dangling images data can free up a lot of space.

Try running `docker system prune --volumes`

This command removes:

- all stopped containers
- all networks not used by at least one container
- all volumes not used by at least one container
- all dangling images
- all dangling build cache

In my case it freed up close to 32GB of disk space

Hope this helps